# Check for specific entry in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check whether a specific entry is present in my database or not. If present then condition,if not then condition. I tried this code but got errors

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
       
$classname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['class']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subjectinfo WHERE class = '{$classname}'", $con);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
    echo "No Such Entry In Table. Please ADD it First.";
    
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Entry Available";
    }       
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Errors :

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\test.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\test.php on line 13
> No Such Entry In Table. Please ADD it First.

Comment: Do not mix MySQL and MySQLi - these are two different extensions.

Comment: You are mixing MySQL APIs - `mysql_` + `mysqli_` = no love. Plus, your DB connection's backwards in your query. The horse comes first ;)

Comment: You're using a `mysql` function on the `mysqli` class... Use `mysqli_num_rows` and `mysqli_query`

Comment: I dont understand difference between mysql and mysqli.

Comment: Please can someone help me with the correct code.

Comment: I have spent 2 hours on this code :D But couldnt figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @MukulAgr *"I dont understand difference between mysql and mysqli difference."* - The difference is that both of those MySQL APIs do not mix together. The `i` stands for "improved", and unlike `mysql_` the DB connection comes first as well for all functions in `mysqli_`. Consult my answer below.

Comment: ...or the other's guy's answer. Either way. His original answer had a major syntax error, which was fixed after. `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM subjectinfo WHERE class = '{$classname}'", $con);` that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like your comments. Make sure you don't mix up mysqli and mysql. mysql is deprecated so you're better off using mysqli.

```html
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$classname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['class']);

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM subjectinfo WHERE class = '{$classname}'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
    echo "No Such Entry In Table. Please ADD it First.";

    }
    else
    {
    echo "Entry Available";
    }       
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing MySQL APIs - `mysql_` + `mysqli_` they do not mix together. Plus, your DB connection's backwards in your query. The connection comes first.

Here:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$classname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['class']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM subjectinfo WHERE class = '{$classname}'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
    echo "No Such Entry In Table. Please ADD it First.";

    }
    else
    {
    echo "Entry Available";
    }       
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Also use `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

Plus, add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

Look into using [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're safer*.

---

*An insight:*

Make sure your form element is indeed named.

I.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="class">
```

otherwise, you will receive an `Undefined index class...` warning.